# ng-repeat filter stops working after data reload

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat in my angular application for a shopping cart. I have created an auto-save which saves the object to local storage and brings it back if the user wants to continue the order. The problem i am having is my filter (that works at first) stops working when the data is loaded from the object. The data is EXACTLY the same, the only thing that doesn't work is the filter. Is there a way to refresh this somehow? i have tried $apply() with no luck. This is my function

```
if(AppStorage.getAutoSave()){
        if(AppStorage.getAutoSave().data){
        $scope.productcodes = [];
        $scope.productcodes = AppStorage.getAutoSave().data;
        $scope.option = AppStorage.getAutoSave().customer;
        $scope.options = AppStorage.getAutoSave().customer2;
        $scope.customerOrderNumber = AppStorage.getAutoSave().ordernum;

        $scope.review(1);

        var lengthofsaved = $scope.orderdetail.length;

        if(lengthofsaved > 0){

             SweetAlert.swal({
                title: "Unsaved Changes",
                text: "We notice you didn't complete a previous order, would you like to restore this?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#54addd",
                confirmButtonText: "New Order",
                cancelButtonText: "Restore",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    AppStorage.setAutoSave(null);
                    location.reload();
                    //SweetAlert.swal("Save file cleared!", "You can now begin inputting a new order.", "success");
                } else {
                    SweetAlert.swal("Restored", "You can now continue your order.", "success");
                }
            });

        }
    }
    }
```

$scope.productcodes is the variable that holds the ng-repeat data, i have double checked and the data is EXACTLY the same as it is when its stored from the data from the API.